# touchpdf : same file is opened with different URLs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pdf

I have div whose content is added dynamically after page load using ajax

this is my content

```js
    function getHref(event,elem){
     event=event || window.event;
     $.Event(event).preventDefault();     
     $('body').on('click','a.view-pdf', function(){    
      var href=$(this).attr('href');
      //alert(href);
      openNav(href); 
     });                                                 
     document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "100%";                         
    }
    function openNav(href) {   
     $("#myNav").pdf( {
      source: href,
     } );
     cross ='<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick=closeNav()>&times;</a>';
        $(".overlay").append(cross);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
  <div class="image-div-conents">
    <h3 class="circle">MB</h3><div style="float:left" class="doc-name-date">
    <span class="bill-name">Tt</span>
    <span class="bill-date">26 Feb, 2017 8:42 PM</span>
  </div>
 </div>
<a style="text-decoration:none" onclick="getHref(event,this);" class="view-pdf" href="http://link.com-A43713_20170226203413_1.pdf">
  <img class="img-responsive" src="http://link.com-A43713_20170226203509_6.jpg" alt="No Image" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src=" text.png"="" ;"="">
  <div class="validitity">
    <span>Validitity:01 Mar, 2018 11:57 AM</span>
  </div>
</a>
```

when user clicks on image a overlay screen will open and pdf file will be opened while debugging i found i am getting different values of but still same pdf file is opened on overlay screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr** do not reuse same DOM node, create one dynamically.

For some reason, [touchpdf](https://github.com/loicminghetti/touchpdf) (the library) doesn't allow to reuse the same tag (best guess).

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
  <div class="image-div-conents">
    <h3 class="circle">MB</h3><div style="float:left" class="doc-name-date">
    <span class="bill-name">Tt</span>
    <span class="bill-date">26 Feb, 2017 8:42 PM</span>
  </div>
</div>
<a style="text-decoration:none" class="view-pdf" href="http://link.com-A43713_20170226203413_1.pdf">
  <img class="img-responsive" src="http://link.com-A43713_20170226203509_6.jpg" alt="No Image" onerror="this.src=text.png">
  <div class="validitity">
    <span>Validitity:01 Mar, 2018 11:57 AM</span>
  </div>
</a>

<!-- Add this to the main page, where you want to show the PDF -->
<div id="overlay"></div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function attachCloseBtn(){
  $("#overlay").prepend('<a href="javascript:void(0)" style="float: right;" class="closebtn" onclick=closeNav()>&times;</a>');
}

function cleanUp(){
  $("#overlay").empty();
}

function getFileName(pdfURI){
  if (typeof pdfURI === "string")
    return pdfURI.split("/").reverse()[0].split(".")[0]
  else 
    throw new TypeError("provide a URI!");
}

window.closeNav function(){
  $("#overlay").empty().hide();
}

$('body').on('click','a.view-pdf', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  openNav(e.currentTarget.href); 
});     

function openNav(pdfURI) {
  // cleaning up first
  cleanUp();

  // preparing dom environment
  var fileName = getFileName(pdfURI);
  attachCloseBtn();
  $("#overlay").append('<div id="'+fileName+'"></div>'); // <-- placeholder for PDF file

  // opening pdf
  $("#"+fileName).pdf({ // <-- do not forget # for the id!
    source: pdfURI
  });
  $("#overlay").show();
}
```

**Old answer**

I'm guessing you're getting side effects from `event=event || window.event;`

Why not using the event directly with jQuery? I edited your HTML markup and removed the `onclick` and `onerror` event listeners.
See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yttL76ye/)

**HTML:**

```
 <a style="text-decoration:none" class="view-pdf" href="http://link.com-A43713_20170226203413_1.pdf">
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$('body').on('click','a.view-pdf', function(e){    
  e.preventDefault();
  var href = e.currentTarget.href;
  openNav(href); 
});                                                           
function openNav(href) {
  // added for debug
  $("#output").append(href);
}
```

Comment: nope getting same issue. i used event=event || window.event; because   e.preventDefault(); does not work in mozilla

Comment: then you must be loading the old pdf again. are you properly removing it on your destroy lifecycle method? If you're using monkey patching on another object, are you calling the method on the correct objects?

Comment: i didn't understand you could you elaborate ?

Comment: is the PDF shown consistent? is the same all the time, with different url? then regardless of the url you're using, `$("#myNav").pdf(...)` shows the same file, which might point to the error being in the `.pdf` method. I would guess that the same file is being used over and over. If you're using a library, maybe there's a cleanup mechanism you have to call upon closing of the file.

Comment: and i am using touchpdf library

Comment: As to the monkey patching remark, say you have an array of objects and want to call a method on each object, method that you attached yourself. Should you use `foreach`, the methods are called on the last object. I had to problem with an implementation of the delegate methods concept in C#.
To avoid this problem, either use `method.bind(objectToCallMethodUpon)` from the caller or in the context of the object, use apply: `method.apply(objectToCallMethodUpon)`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136742/discussion-between-java-rmi-and-sumi-straessle).